# How to write nested queries using sequelize in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, subquery

I'm trying to write nested queries using sequelize of this query.

```
const userIdPriorityLevel = await db.sequelize.query(
            `select "p_level" from roles  where id=(select "roleId" from users where id='${userId}');`
            , { raw: true });
```

the above query works like this

**user table**

```
id   roleId
1     2
2     3
```

**roles table**

```
id   p_level
2     4324
3     3423
```

please help how to do that.

**updated:**

```
        const userIdPriorityLevel = await db.Role.findAll({
            attributes: ['p_level'],
            include: [{
                model: db.User,
                required: true,
                attributes: [],
                where: {
                    id: userId
                }
            }
            ]
        })

        console.log("userid   ", userIdPriorityLevel)
```

when i print the above query it gives me this output

```
userid    [
  role {
    dataValues: { p_level: 700 },
    _previousDataValues: { p_level: 700 },
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      include: [Array],
      includeNames: [Array],
      includeMap: [Object],
      includeValidated: true,
      attributes: [Array],
      raw: true
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

i want to extract only this `p_level: 700` value from above output. trying something like this

```
  const userPriorityLevel = userIdPriorityLevel[0][0]['p_level']
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Rewrite this plain SQL query to a Sequelize one? Or just correct it somehow?

Comment: Rewrite this plain SQL query to a Sequelize one

Comment: Did you already define Sequelize models and associations?

Comment: yes, i did this ```User.belongsTo(Role)``` where ```user``` and ```role``` both are tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you also have `Role.hasMany(User)` association you can try something like this:

```js
const roles = await Roles.findAll({
  attributes: ['p_level'],
  include: [{
    model: User,
    required: true,
    attributes: [],
    where: {
      id: userId
    }
  }
  ]
})
```

**Update:** to get plain objects from Sequelize query call `get({ plain: true })` for each model instance:

```js
const plainRoles = roles.map(x => x.get({ plain: true }))
```

Comment: it works, thanks. but when i want the p_level value from its output, please check my updated question.

Comment: see updated answer